# Observed flux of a non-spherical object

Tags: visible-light, astrophysics, astronomy

I recently had an exercise for which I had to find the observed flux of an annulus (accretion disc of a black hole). With the assumption that the annulus behaves as a perfect black body, the provided solution is $$F_{\nu\text{, obs}}=\frac{A}{d^2}B_\nu(T)\tag1$$ where $A$ is the surface area of one side of the annulus, i.e. $A=\pi\left(r_{\text{out}}^2-r_{\text{in}}^2\right)$, $d$ is the distance to the observer and $B_\nu(T)$ is the Planck function at the temperature $T$ of the accretion disc.

I am trying to understand how this formula can be derived. In my lecture we had that for a spherical object (i.e. a star), the observed flux is $$F_{\nu\text{, obs}}=\left(\frac{R_\star}{d}\right)^2\pi B_\nu(T_\star)\tag2$$ Here I understand how to get this result: Using that the flux at the surface is $F_\nu=\pi B_\nu(T_\star)$ – why this is the case is another question but irrelevant for now – then the luminosity is the flux multiplied with the surface area of the star, $L=4\pi R_\star^2\pi B_\nu(T_\star)$. When observed at a distance $d$, this has to be spread over the surface area of a sphere with radius $d$, i.e. to get the observed flux we have to divide by $4\pi d^2$ and get the result $(2)$.

If I try to apply the same procedure to the accretion disc, the surface area is $2\pi\left(r_{\text{out}}^2-r_{\text{in}}^2\right)$ since we consider both sides; then $L=2\pi^2\left(r_{\text{out}}^2-r_{\text{in}}^2\right)B_\nu(T)=2\pi A\,B_\nu(T)$ and I would get $$F_{\nu\text{, obs}}=\frac{A}{2d^2}B_\nu(T)\tag3$$ which is off by a factor of $\frac12$ from the correct result $(1)$. I suspect that this is because the assumption that the light is evenly spread over the sphere with radius $d$ is not a good one for objects that aren't spherically symmetrical themselves. When I asked my tutor about where $(1)$ comes from I was told that it's just an approximation.

**Is there a general method of finding the observed flux for a non spherically symmetric object?**

---

<sub>I am aware that this question is dangerously close to being homework-like but I think since the focus is on understanding the derivation of the formula and not an actual computation, it should be fine.</sub>

Comment: [An annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) and disk are different shapes that have different areas; you seem to be using the two words interchangeably (likely due to the fact one generally calls it an accretion disc).

Comment: Yes I mean an annulus whenever I refer to a disc - thanks for pointing it out! I'll edit for more clarity

Comment: Eq (3) is supposed to be for the accretion disk, which is an annulus of area $\pi \Delta (r^2)$ while you've used the area for a full disk ($2\pi \Delta (r^2)$), or am I mistaken?